# Jquery Close/ expand all button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm looking to correct the jquery that controls the expand/ close all buttons. I've placed the offending jquery in a second code block. If you click on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aS8wN/3/) you should get a better idea of what I'm talking about. Right now the buttons aren't working properly and I've managed to set a double toggle (if that makes sense) on .faq-row > h2 and .faq-row > h3

```js
var faqCategories = $('.categories');
var faqContainers = faqCategories.find('.container-toggle').hide();

var faqRow = faqCategories.find('.faq-row');
var faqRowItems = faqRow.find('.faq-row-answer').hide();    

$('.categories > h2').click(function() {
  faqCategories.removeClass('active');
  faqContainers.slideUp();
  $(this).parent(faqCategories).addClass('active')
  $(this).next().slideDown();
  return false;
});

$('.faq-row > h3').click(function() {
  faqRow.removeClass('active');
  faqRowItems.slideUp();
  $(this).parent(faqRow).addClass('active')
  $(this).next().slideDown();
  return false;
});
```

And now for the offending jquery.

```js
$(".category-expand .expandAll").click(function() {
    $(".closeAll").toggleClass("hider");
    $(this).toggleClass("hider");      
    $(this).closest('.mainContent').find('.container-toggle').slideToggle('fast'); 
});

$("category-expand .closeAll").click(function() {
    $(".expandAll").toggleClass("hider");
    $(this).toggleClass("hider");
    $(this).closest('.mainContent').find('.container-toggle').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you wire up onClick of closeAll button, the css selector is missing  the '.' before category-expand class selector, it should be like that:

```
$(".category-expand .closeAll").click(function() {
$(".expandAll").toggleClass("hider");
$(this).toggleClass("hider");
$(this).closest('.mainContent').find('.container-toggle').slideToggle('fast'); });
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aS8wN/4/